# How to create Regex pattern for fluentd

Tags: regex, fluentd

I am trying to parse `daemon logs` from my linux machine to `elastic search` using `fluentd` but having hard time creating `regex` pattern for it. Below are few of the logs from the daemon logs:

```
Jun  5 06:46:14 user avahi-daemon[309]: Registering new address record for fe80::a7c0:8b54:ee45:ea4 on wlan0.*.
Jun  5 06:46:14 user dhcpcd[337]: wlan0: deleting default route via fe80::1e56:feff:fe13:2da
Jun  5 06:46:14 user dhcpcd[337]: wlan0: deleting route to 2402:3a80:9db:48da::/64
Jun  5 06:46:14 user dhcpcd[337]: wlan0: deleting address fe80::a7c0:8b54:ee45:ea4
Jun  5 06:46:14 user avahi-daemon[309]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::a7c0:8b54:ee45:ea4 on wlan0.
Jun  5 06:46:14 user avahi-daemon[309]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::a7c0:8b54:ee45:ea4.
```

So as you can see from the above logs, first we have the `time` of the logs, then we have the `username` and the `daemon name`, followed by the `message`.

I want to create below json format for the above logs:

```
{
    "time": "Jun  5 06:46:14",
    "username": "user",
    "daemon": "avahi-daemon[309]",
    "msg": "Registering new address record for fe80::a7c0:8b54:ee45:ea4 on wlan0.*."
}

{
    "time": "Jun  5 06:46:14",
    "username": "user",
    "daemon": "dhcpcd[337]: wlan0",
    "msg": "deleting default route via fe80::1e56:feff:fe13:2da"
}
```

Can anyone please give me some help on this. Is there any tool which we can use to generate regex in fluentd.

Edit:

I have managed to get few things matched from the logs like:

```
^(?<time>^(.*?:.*?):\d\d) (?<username>[^ ]*) matches Jun  5 06:46:14 user
```

but when I am passing this in [fluentular](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/parse?regexp=%5E%28%3F%3Ctime%3E.*%3F%3A.*%3F%29%3A%24&input=Jun+we%3Art%3Ahn+raspberrypi&time_format=), its not showing any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `^(?<time>[A-Za-z]{3}\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s(?<username>[^ ]+)\s+(?<daemon>[^:]+):\s+(?<message>.*)$`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ppQoIP/1/)